# What's the difference between toilet master Jack RT100 and 40275 models?

Tags: toilet

I see home depot/lowes selling a "toilet master jack RT100" and walmart selling a "Toilet Master Jack 40275 Universal Fit"

Is there a difference between the model numbers?

https://thetoiletmaster.com/toilet-master-jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the manufacturer and they said they are the same model.

Comment: Yes, just to make life more challenging, many large stores sell products with unique product numbers that are identical to products with different numbers at other stores.  Part of their sad game is also to hinder comparison shopping.  Furthermore, it provides them with an unethical excuse to refuse price matching, because "it's not the same item", even though the items are identical.